# Add column based on a reference column (Forex Rate, R laguage)

Tags: r

I want to add Forex Rate reference to large data. Are there easy ways to do this?

**A(data.frame)**

```
   Price      Date
1   100    2018-10-14
2   103    2018-10-16
3   102    2018-10-18
N   etc       etc
```

**B(data.frame)**

```
    Date      Forex Rate
1 2018-10-14       28
2 2018-10-15       22
3 2018-10-16       30
N    etc          etc
```

**C(data.frame)**

```
   price     Date    Forex Rate
1   100    2018-10-14     28
2   103    2018-10-16     30
3   102    2018-10-18     39
N   etc       etc         etc
```

I have A and B. 
Intend to generate C by adding B (Forex Rate Reference), sorted by *Date*.

Comment: Is this a case of `merge` or `dplyr::left_join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data shown in the question seems a little inconsistent (e.g., where does "39" come from?), but I suspect this can be resolved with joins/merges.

Some consumable data:

```r
A <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text="
   Price      Date
   100    2018-10-14
   103    2018-10-16
   102    2018-10-18")

B <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text="
    Date      Forex_Rate
 2018-10-14       28
 2018-10-15       22
 2018-10-16       30")
```

### Base R

```r
merge(A, B, by = "Date", all = TRUE)
#         Date Price Forex_Rate
# 1 2018-10-14   100         28
# 2 2018-10-15    NA         22
# 3 2018-10-16   103         30
# 4 2018-10-18   102         NA
```

### `dplyr`

```r
dplyr::full_join(A, B, by = "Date")
#   Price       Date Forex_Rate
# 1   100 2018-10-14         28
# 2   103 2018-10-16         30
# 3   102 2018-10-18         NA
# 4    NA 2018-10-15         22
```

### `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
ADT <- as.data.table(A)
BDT <- as.data.table(B)
merge(ADT, BDT, by = "Date", all = TRUE)
#          Date Price Forex_Rate
# 1: 2018-10-14   100         28
# 2: 2018-10-15    NA         22
# 3: 2018-10-16   103         30
# 4: 2018-10-18   102         NA
```

This looks the same, but under the hood it is using `data.table:::merge.data.table`, which preserves some of `data.tables` ancillary advantages. If you're looking to do left-joins, though, its syntax can still use `merge` or use the slightly different syntax:

```r
# equivalent to dplyr::left_join(ADT, BDT, by = "Date") or merge(ADT, BDT, by = "Date", all.x = TRUE)
BDT[ADT, on = "Date"]
#          Date Forex_Rate Price
# 1: 2018-10-14         28   100
# 2: 2018-10-16         30   103
# 3: 2018-10-18         NA   102
```